# Bars to be plotted over map

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, rworldmap

I want to draw barchart over map as on this page: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16162_01/web.1112/e16181/dv_map.htm#BEHHAFEJ

[image: example]

I used following data and code but it is not working.

```
ddf = read.table(header=T, sep=",", text="
country, val1, val2, val3
Nigeria,5,10,8
China,8,12,20
Brazil,15,9,20
Italy,9,25,5
Australia,15,5,25
")

require (rworldmap)

sPDF <- joinCountryData2Map(ddf
    , joinCode = "NAME"
    , nameJoinColumn = "country"
    , verbose = TRUE)

mapBars( sPDF, 
       , nameZs=c(ddf$val1, ddf$val2, ddf$val3)
       , symbolSize=4 )
```

How can I correct this? Please help.

---

Edit: 
I tried using code in answer below but I am getting an empty window plot with error: Error in par(plt = c(xyx, xyy), new = TRUE) : 
  invalid value specified for graphical parameter "plt"
[image]

Comment: Actually you need to pass the names to parameter nameZs, i.e. `nameZs=c('val1','val2','val3')`. Anyway, mapBars draws one single vertical bar divided in 3 values, not 3 vartical bars side-by-side...

Comment: Thanks. It works. But is there no way the bars can be side by side, like "besides=TRUE" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using subplots:

```
# ...
plot(getMap())
df <- merge(x=ddf, y=sPDF@data[sPDF@data$ADMIN, c("ADMIN", "LON", "LAT")], by.x="country", by.y="ADMIN", all.x=TRUE)
require(TeachingDemos)
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) 
  subplot(barplot(height=as.numeric(as.character(unlist(df[i, 2:4], use.names=F))), 
                  axes=F, 
                  col=rainbow(3), ylim=range(df[,2:4])),
          x=df[i, 'LON'], y=df[i, 'LAT'], size=c(.3, .3))
legend("topright", legend=names(df[, 2:4]), fill=rainbow(3))
```

[image]

Comment: It is not working. After last line, I am getting this error: Error in par(plt = c(xyx, xyy), new = TRUE) : invalid value specified for graphical parameter "plt"

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Try without the param.

Comment: Please see edit in my initial post above. I have put a screenshot of the error. Your graph is exactly what I want.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot reproduce it. I'm on Win7 x64, TeachingDemos 2.9, R version 3.0.2. Maybe an update helps?

Comment: I tried in windows7*32 as well as 64bit, R version 3.1.0. I hope I am using correct code. I am putting my code till sPDF<-.. line (omitting mapBars(sPDF,... line). Then I am putting your code. Is there a mistake here? Also, str(sPDF@data) has 2 columns named ADMIN (9th column & 2nd last column). Maybe that is causing problems.

Comment: Now I see your problem - you need to plot the world map, first (I used all of your code for `#...`). Try `plot(getMap())` or sth before the for loop.

Comment: It worked. Thanks for your help. There is no legend but I think that will need another question.

Comment: no prob. I updated the code so that it (1) includes a legend and (2) doesn't mess up the order of the plots (merge instead of cbind).