# Barplot over map getting values mixed up

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, rworldmap

I am plotting bar chart over map with following code as suggested on: [Bars to be plotted over map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231569/bars-to-be-plotted-over-map)

```
    ddf = read.table(header=T, sep=",", text="
    country, val1, val2, val3
    Nigeria,5,10,8
    China,25,12,20
    Brazil,50,9,20
    Italy,75,25,5
    Australia,100,5,25
    ")

ddf = structure(list(country = structure(c(5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("Australia", 
"Brazil", "China", "Italy", "Nigeria"), class = "factor"), val1 = c(5L, 
25L, 50L, 75L, 100L), val2 = c(10L, 12L, 9L, 25L, 5L), val3 = c(8L, 
20L, 20L, 5L, 25L)), .Names = c("country", "val1", "val2", "val3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

    require (rworldmap)

    sPDF <- joinCountryData2Map(ddf
        , joinCode = "NAME"
        , nameJoinColumn = "country"
        , verbose = TRUE)

    plot(getMap())

    require(TeachingDemos)
    df <- cbind(ddf, sPDF@data[sPDF@data$ADMIN %in% ddf$country, c("LON", "LAT")])
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) 
      subplot(barplot(height=unlist(df[i, 2:4], use.names=F), 
                      axes=F, 
                      col=rainbow(3), ylim=range(df[,2:4])),
              x=df[i, 'LON'], y=df[i, 'LAT'], size=c(.3, .3))
```

The bars are getting plotted very well but the sizes are not corresponding. The plot looks like following (notice that the highest first bar is over Nigeria and not Australia and Brazil's first bar should be bigger than China's):

[image]

Comment: What is the map adding to this? Why not just do a set of barplots?

Comment: I think plotting over a map gives a clearer message but it may be personal preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason behind that was you are doing **blind cbind**... And data returned by `sPDF@data[sPDF@data$ADMIN %in% ddf$country, c("LON", "LAT")]` is not in same seq as they are in ddf.. Try this

```
df <- merge(x = ddf, y = sPDF@data[sPDF@data$ADMIN %in% ddf$country, c('ADMIN',"LON", "LAT")],
            by.x= 'country', by.y = 'ADMIN')
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) 
  subplot(barplot(height=unlist(df[i, 2:4], use.names=F), 
                  axes=F, 
                  col=rainbow(3), ylim=range(df[,2:4])),
          x=df[i, 'LON'], y=df[i, 'LAT'], size=c(.3, .3))
```

Result after this would be

[image]

In above graph range for all bar chart is same i.e. 5 to 100 what you have mentioned in your code snippet.

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks. But the location of barplots gets disturbed (go away from respective countries) if the window is resized. Can that be corrected?