# Beside=F not working in barplot in subplot in R

Tags: r, plot, rworldmap

I am trying to make stacked barplot from code on this page:[Bars to be plotted over map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231569/bars-to-be-plotted-over-map)

But following code which contains beside=FALSE still draws side-by-side bars and not stacked barchart.

```
ddf = read.table(header=T, sep=",", text="
country, val1, val2, val3
Nigeria,5,10,8
China,8,12,20
Brazil,15,9,20
Italy,9,25,5
Australia,15,5,25
")

require (rworldmap)

sPDF <- joinCountryData2Map(ddf
    , joinCode = "NAME"
    , nameJoinColumn = "country"
    , verbose = TRUE)


plot(getMap())
df <- merge(x=ddf, y=sPDF@data[sPDF@data$ADMIN, c("ADMIN", "LON", "LAT")], by.x="country", by.y="ADMIN", all.x=TRUE)
require(TeachingDemos)
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) 
  subplot(barplot(height=as.numeric(as.character(unlist(df[i, 2:4], use.names=F))), 
                  axes=F, beside=FALSE,
                  col=rainbow(3), ylim=range(df[,2:4])),
          x=df[i, 'LON'], y=df[i, 'LAT'], size=c(.3, .3))
legend("topright", legend=names(df[, 2:4]), fill=rainbow(3))
```

What could be the reason and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for besides to work, `hight` has to be a matrix with 1 column. So try:

```
plot(getMap())
df <- merge(x=ddf, y=sPDF@data[sPDF@data$ADMIN, c("ADMIN", "LON", "LAT")], by.x="country", by.y="ADMIN", all.x=TRUE)
require(TeachingDemos)
for (i in 1:nrow(df))
  height <- matrix(as.numeric(as.character(unlist(df[i, 2:4], use.names=F))), ncol=1)
  subplot(barplot(height=height, 
                  axes=F, beside=FALSE,
                  col=rainbow(3), ylim=range(df[,2:4])),
          x=df[i, 'LON'], y=df[i, 'LAT'], size=c(.3, .3))
legend("topright", legend=names(df[, 2:4]), fill=rainbow(3))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks. The height<-matrix(..  statement needs to come in the for loop.